# Query to get the count of records from MS Access database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, oledb

I am using below code to get the count of records present in database, but somehow it is not working.

throwing me an error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

```
conn.Open();                       
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
cmd1.CommandText = "select count(*) from Orders_Description where (ItemCode=" + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value) + ") and (OrderId=" + Convert.ToInt32(txtOrderNo.Text) + ")";
int recordExists = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
if (recordExists > 0)
{
    //Insert command if record exists.
}
```

Comment: What are the values of `row.Cells[1].Value` and `txtOrderNo.Text` exactly? What is your `CurrentCulture`? Debug your code and tell us. And please always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: `row.Cells[1].Value` and `txtOrderNo.Text` contains integer values and in database as well it has a type integer

Comment: Your comment doesn't help at all. What are these values **exactly**? What is the type of `ItemCode` and `OrderId` columns?

Comment: type of `OrderId` and `ItemCode` is Number in MS access database. I wanted to check the entered `ItemCode` with respect to `OrderId` is exists in database or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is coming from the `Convert.ToInt32` where you are building your SQL query. This means that either `txtOrderNo.Text` or `row.Cells[1].Value` contain non-integer values, decimal points or are just empty strings. From the MSDN documentation for [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) a `FormatException` will be thrown when:

> value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).

Additionally, you (try to) convert the numbers to `Int32` but then use them as strings, a redundant operation. The simple solution would be to remove the conversion operation but that will still leave you with an invalid SQL statement and very open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: thanks `@DavidG`... I was converting the blank text field to integer. That's the reason of causing error.

Answer (score 0):

u need single quotations before and after values assigned to OrderId in case datatype of that field is nvarchar equivalent (not numeric).

your code :

(OrderId=" + Convert.ToInt32(txtOrderNo.Text) + ")";

correct code with single qutations inserted :

(OrderId='" + txtOrderNo.Text + "')";

Comment: How do you know that `ItemCode` column type? It it is numerical, OP will not need to use single quotes.

Comment: as i explained, its in case datatype of that field is nvarchar equivalent (not numeric)

Comment: @MladenOršolić : I tried with single quotations, but gives the same error.. `ItemCode` and `OrderId` has a Integer type in database

Comment: could it be a missing semi colon at the end of the query?